# SSRS Chart series title not show all text

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts

I make Chart Report using SSRS

I have problem is my long series label not show whole text For Example

if label is "Personal Computer" it's show "Personal C......"

see image below

[image]

and this is whole Chart area

[image]

it's have more space between legend and series label I want to use this space to show whole text like this

[image]

How to fix this problem ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the Chart Area height so that it is approximately half the height of the chart. This then allows sufficient space for the x axis labels.
You also nee to set the minimum and maximum font sizes for the x-axis.
I suggest between 6 and 8 pt.

Try setting the label rotation to 90 degrees instead of 45 also make sure the x axis interval is set to 1 and not auto.

[ Also have a look at this article ] 
(http://www.douglane.net/fit-chart-labels-in-ssrs/)

Comment: Thank for reply I edit height Chart Area but it x axis area not expand  it's still have problem

Comment: what version of Reporting Services are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Add the Legend on Right side of the Bar chart and Check

Comment: Thank you but this is not my problem my problem is series label not show whole text 

For Example my full text is "Personal computer" it's show "Personal C......"